# Is it possible to search "My Places" in Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth, google-earth-pro

The search feature in Google Earth appears to only search the Google database.  Is there a way to make it search the My Places content on ones own computer?

I read that a My Places search was possible in older versions (circa 2010) using CTRL+F, but this does not appear to work in the current version, 7.1.2.2041, which was released 10/7/2013.

Answer (score 2):

While the CTRL+F trick no longer works, it is still possible to search your My Places content.  This is accomplished using the search field at the bottom of the Places panel in the Sidebar.  Note that this is not the same as the search field at the top of the Sidebar.

If you don't see the Sidebar, you can toggle it on using the main menu, View > Sidebar.

If you see the Sidebar but no My Places listing, note that you can expand/collapse the Places panel by clicking on "Places".

Comment: This helped. Thanks! It actually works with Ctrl+F - it activates the sidebar you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

I use <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> and it search through my places, It doesn't shortlist found result only, but still can go to searched places with up and down arrow beside place find search box.

I tested using Google Earth Pro.